# Pointer Mismatches & Trouble

Tags: c++, pointers

Trying to make a vector of pointers and then each pointer is set to NULL. I then want to make a certain part of the vector be connected to a node I allocated. I am having some struggles with the mismatch. I also want to add the content that was already there to back of the new node. Any feedback would be kind. I keep getting seg fault.

```
struct Node{
    int x;
    Node* rest;
};

void HTadd (int k, Node *ptr)
{

    Node* temp = new Node
    temp->x = k;
    temp->rest= ptr;
    ptr = temp;
}


int main ()
{
    vector <Node *> tableP;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    tableP.push_back(NULL);}

    Node * buggy = tableP[0];
    HTadd(26, buggy);
    cout << buggy->key << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: quick question. why `temp->rest = ptr;`? `rest` will always be assigned to `null` for all the vectors is it not?

Comment: Yeah but suppose the vector already has a linked-list of nodes, I want to put my temp node before the linked-list already in there and just attach the linked-list to temp->rest

Comment: yes right now in this implementation it not useful. maybe as you add code it makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the definition of HTadd as so

```
void HTadd (int k, Node *&ptr)
```

call it normally as you did.

reason: referencing a variable means giving different name to the same location. if you use just `Node * ptr` then you are just passing by value. i.e `ptr` is a local variable which will have the copy of the value in `buggy`(which is `null`). what you do to `ptr` does not affect `buggy`. so to make changes to `buggy` when `ptr` is changed, pass `buggy` by reference. so `ptr` should e declared as `reference to a pointer to Node`

EDIT: now as per the below comment `Node * buggy = tableP[1];` wil make buggy hold the address returned by `new node`(tableP[1] holds this address). now after the call to `HTadd(26,buggy);`, buggy is given a new value by `ptr = temp` (coz temp = new node). now buggy points to something else but tableP[1] is unchanged i.e `tableP[1]->rest` is still `NULL` so tableP[1]->rest->x has no meaning. hence seg fault.
why tableP[1] is unghanged? coz tableP[1] is one variable and`buggy` is another variable both of type Node * so `Node * buggy = tableP[1]` jus copies contents of tableP[1] to buggy;

Comment: Can you explain this a bit?

Comment: One more question ! :) so i did the following to test it .... tableP[1] = new Node;
    tableP[1]->x = 66;
    tableP[1]->rest = NULL;
    Node * buggy = tableP[1];
    cout << buggy->x<<endl;
    HTadd(26, buggy);
    cout << tableP[1]->x<<endl;
    cout << (tableP[1]->rest)->x << endl; 

and i get a seg fault... shouldnt it print out "26-> 66" like thats what I was trying to make a node connected to a node

Comment: what i meant by "26->66" was like 26 would be in the first node in tableP[1] and then 66 would be connected to the 26 node

Comment: @Masterminder see what happens in `HTadd(26,buggy)` is is you. i'l edit  my answer check it.

Comment: if i do the following "cout <<"PT :"<< ptr->x<<endl;
    cout <<"PT 2:"<< (ptr->rest)->x<<endl;" it is connecting but like for some reason when i try to access through tableP[1] it wont recall it

Comment: so how would I make it so I can access tableP[1]->x etc...? because that is what I wanted.

Comment: Why is it when i set a pointer to tableP[1] and i want to iterate through it i get a seg fault??? I want to make a pointer to tableP[1] called temper and then just iterate through the linked list so I can print each x value. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26134/discussion-between-koushik-and-masterminder)

Answer (score 4):

Notice that I changed the function declaration of `HTAdd` to take in a pointer to a pointer to a `Node`. Since you wanted to modify the contents of the first element of the vector, which is a `Node*`, you need to pass in `Node**` to `HTAdd`.

EDIT: My original code doesn't really change the 0th vector element to be connected to the Node you're trying to add. Here's how you would do it. As you can see, the last two `cout` statements print the contents of the 0th element of the vector and `buggy`, which point to the same address.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int x;
    Node* rest;
};

void HTadd (int k, Node **ptr) {
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->x = k;
    temp->rest= *ptr;
    *ptr = temp;
}


int main ()
{
    vector<Node*> tableP;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        tableP.push_back(NULL);
    }


    HTadd(26, &tableP[0]);
    Node *buggy = tableP[0];

    cout << tableP[0]->x << endl;
    cout << buggy->x << endl;

    cout << tableP[0] << endl;
    cout << buggy << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I access it using something like... tableP[0]->key ? I get a seg fault if I try to do that

Comment: @Koushik i meant x**   this gives me seg fault ... (tableP[0])->x

Comment: Isn't tableP[0] a pointer? so a pointer to x should display it, right?

Comment: @Masterminder yes it is a pointer and yes it should display. and yes its working fine for me. where exactly do you call the `tableP[0]->x`?after or before the HTadd() call?

Comment: @Koushik Ohh Okay, I did not see the edit done by Ivan Gozali. So to summarize just so I understand everything... I have a vector of Node* Pointers. So when I pass in "HTadd(26, &tableP[0]);" I am dereferencing the pointer to the vector? the "void HTadd (int k, Node **ptr)" is slightly confusing :(

Answer (score 3):

buggy is NULL and you are deferencing it. You are passing the pointer by value and not by reference, so you change its contents, but not what it points to.  Change HTAdd to take a reference to a pointer as its second parameter.

Comment: +1... a reference to a pointer is arguably easier to understand and use as intended inside HTadd than the pointer-to-pointer approach, as well as being a simpler change to the existing code.

Comment: @Fred Thomson How would your implementations look like?

Comment: @TonyD How would your implementation look like? In terms of accessing and setting?

Comment: @Masterminder: the only change to the code you'd written (as per your question) is a "&" character indicating acceptance of the parameter by reference in this line: `void HTadd (int k, Node*& ptr)`... that way `ptr` is not an independent variable local to `HTadd`, but a reference/alias to the caller's argument (`buggy`), with `buggy` being updated by the existing `*ptr = temp;`.